# Compare two CSV files and output only rows with the specific columns that are different

Tags: python

I have two CSV files with 6 columns each and both have one common column `EmpID` (the primary key for comparison). For Example, `File1.csv` is:

```
EmpID1,Name1,Email1,City1,Phone1,Hobby1
120034,Tom Hanks,tom.hanks@gmail.com,Mumbai,8888999,Fishing
```

And `File2.csv` is

```
EmpID2,Name2,Email2,City2,Phone2,Hobby2
120034,Tom Hanks,hanks.tom@gmail.com,Mumbai,8888999,Running
```

The files need to be compared for differences and only rows and columns that are different should be added into a new output file as

```
EmpID1,Email1,Email2,Hobby1,Hobby2
120034,tom.hanks@gmail.com,hanks.tom@gmail.com,Fishing,Running
```

Currently I have written the below piece of code in Python. Now I am wondering on how to identify and pick the differences. Any pointers and help will be much appreciated.

```
import csv
import os
os.getcwd()
os.chdir('filepath')

with open('File1.csv', 'r') as csv1, open('File2.csv', 'r') as csv2:

    file1 = csv1.readlines()`
    file2 = csv2.readlines()`

with open('OutputFile.csv', 'w') as output:

    for line in file1:`
        if line not in file2:
            output.write(line)

output.close()
csv1.close()
csv2.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Will improvise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the files to a dict structure, with the 'EMPID' as key pointing to the entire row:

```
import csv
fieldnames = [] # to store all fieldnames
with open('File1.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    data1 = {row['EMPID1']: row for row in cf}
    fieldnames.extend(cf.fieldnames)

with open('File2.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
    data2 = {row['EMPID2']: row for row in cf}
    fieldnames.extend(cf.fieldnames)
```

Then identify all ids that are in both dicts:

```
ids_to_check = set(data1) & set(data2)
```

Finally, iterate over the ids and compare the rows themselves

```
with open('OutputFile.csv', 'w') as f:
    cw = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, delimiter=',')
    cw.writeheader()
    for id in ids_to_check:
        diff = compare_dict(data1[id], data2[id], fieldnames)
        if diff:
            cw.writerow(diff)
```

Here's the `compare_dict` function implementation:

```
def compare_dict(d1, d2, fields_compare):
    fields_compare = set(field.rstrip('12') for field in fields_compare)
    if any(d1[k + '1'] != d2[k + '2'] for k in fields_compare):
        # they differ, return a new dict with all fields
        result = d1.copy()
        result.update(d2)
        return result
    else:
        return {}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. Will try this.

Comment: The dict lib worked and I modified the code to:

def compare_dict(d1, d2):
    if any(d1[k + '1'] != d2[k + '2'] for k in 
            ['EMPID', 'Name', 'Email']):
        # they differ, return a new dict with all fields
        result = d1.copy()
        result.update(d2)
        if result['Email1'] != result['Email2']:
            result['Result']=0
        return result
    else:
        return {} 

But, overall the code looks good for certain number of columns, if i have 30+ columns in both files, is there a way of not to mention columns names in code.

Comment: you could read the column names from the files first, of course @Shins - I edited the code to add that.

Comment: @Shins if the solution works for you, please mark it as accepted to finalize the question workflow. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information.

Comment: Just did. Thanks.